# Accessing documents stored in Amazon's S3

Tags: amazon-s3

We are building a system which will allow users to store documents (images or pdf) in s3.  These files can later be accessed via their URL like (https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/person/2/provider/test1.png)).  We have no problem uploading and deleting documents in s3 using proper IAM keys and AWS SDK.  However, when we try to access documents using their URL, we get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>V0DTW6T3F6J3ZFDG</RequestId>
<HostId>ZOiybrTAfx8t+NZQW2cpS4nw8vNhmQaemFfinQSBP41K2mZhDItF29156LTUwZh+SqZacfssLIE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I understand the reason for the error but don't know how to resolve it.

Basically, we are building a health related portal.  Patients can upload their documents (health records).  Later on we want them to be able to view their documents while they are logged in.  The idea was that the documents could be displayed via their URL.

The only solution I can think of is to first download the document locally (whether that is on the browser's local filesystem or on the mobile device if accessed through a mobile app) and then displayed from there.  That does not sound like an ideal way.  The other alternative is to make the bucket completely public which is not acceptable because these are health care records.

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you providing a presigned URL for the user to access the documents?

Comment: We are not but primarily because we did not know about them.

Comment: I want to add that the user (patient) can upload any number of healthcare documents (pdf or images).  We do not know about their names and how many in advance.

Comment: I just tried presigned URL and that might work for us.  Thanks.